# why is segmention fault while printing?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

This is my x86 assembly code:

```
section .data 
  output db '%d',10,0
section .text 
  global main
  extern printf 
main :
  xor ecx,ecx
  xor eax,eax
  mov eax,1
  mov ecx,5
lable1:
  push ecx 
  push eax  
  cmp eax,0
  jg print
  pop eax
  pop ecx
  inc eax
loop lable1 
  ret 
print:
  push eax
  push output
  call printf 
  add esp,8
  ret
```

This program should print all numbers between 1 to 5.
Why am I getting a segmentation fault after printing '1'?

Comment: Have a look at the calling convention/ABI links in [the x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).  You could keep your counters in call-preserved registers instead of trying to push/pop them across printf.

Answer (score 4):

`print` ends with a `ret` instruction, which implies that it is something that you should `call`. So `jg print` should be `jng skip` / `call print` / `skip:` (or just `call print`, because the `> 0` check seems unnecessary).
 `call` places the return address on the stack, `jg` does not.

Comment: I know check is unnecessary . i just want to know why doesnt it return to main after printing 1 and keep going main to print and print 1 to 5. @Michael

Comment: Like I said, you need to use `call` if you expect `ret` to work.

Comment: what can i do if i want to use jg instruction and ret it to main again.             I want to print number if it is  greater than 0.                                                    (P.S.  This is just sample code that i wrote for jg error. ) @Michael

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you keep getting faults is: **You are ignoring the stack!**

Your `lable1` subroutine is correctly set up, but with your `jg` you eject from it ignoring the stack - leaving the stack corrupt.

```
lable1:
  push ecx 
  push eax  
  cmp eax,0
  jg print
  pop eax
  pop ecx
  inc eax
```

You

```
xor eax,eax     ; EAX = 0 - breaking pipeline
mov eax,1       ; EAX = 1 - which is redundant
```

but because of your

```
cmp eax,0
jg print
```

in the `lable1` subroutine, you jump to the `print:` routine if EAX is greater than `0`(and it is in the first iteration with EAX=1) with a stack offset of `-8` caused by

```
push ecx 
push eax
```

in the beginning of `lable1:`. The `ret`ting from `print:`, which cleans up the stack properly by `add esp,8` at the end, will cause your program to return to the address of the first entry of the stack, which you have assigned to [ESP]=(former EAX = 1) in main:`mov eax,1`.

Therefore you get a `SegFault`, because you try to jump/return to the address [00000001] (=EAX=1,32bit).